# mouse enter/out function affect only the closest div

Tags: jquery, mouseenter, onmouseout

**HTML**

```
<div class="up-score">up-score</div>

<div class="vframe">vframe</div>

<div class="lol">lol</div>

<hr>

<div class="up-score">up-score</div>

<div class="vframe">vframe</div>

<div class="lol">lol</div>    

<hr>

<div class="up-score">up-score</div>

<div class="vframe">vframe</div>

<div class="lol">lol</div>
```

**css**

```
.lol { display: none; }
```

**Jquery**

```
var timer
$('.up-score').mouseenter(function(){clearTimeout(timer);$('.vframe').parent().find('.lol').fadeIn(1000)})
$('.up-score').mouseout(function(){timer = setTimeout(function(){$('.vframe').parent().find('.lol').fadeOut(1000);}, 500);})
```

Right now when I hover over any up-score div it shows all the lol's divs. I just want to affect only the lol div and is within the `<hr>`

[JS FIDDLE LINK](http://jsfiddle.net/1bdkjt5c/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Use `next()` in jquery

```
  var timer;
$('.up-score').mouseenter(function(){clearTimeout(timer);$(this).next().next('.lol').fadeIn(1000)});

$('.up-score').mouseout(function(){
    var _this = this;
    timer = setTimeout(function(){  $(_this).next().next('.lol').fadeOut(1000);
                                }, 500);
});
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/1bdkjt5c/7/)

Comment: they are not fading out on mouse out.

Comment: hover works, but does it work with the var timer? I really need that.

Comment: if you move the mouse up and down fast, some or all of the lols won't fade out. Also, using .next() is not ideal for me, this is a simplified example. On my website there might be 15+ divs in between up-score and lol

Comment: @Newbie - Now check the fiddle and tell me if not comes we are go to another way

Comment: Almost, but if you hover the 3rd upscore and quickly then leave mouse hovering over the 2nd upscore the 3rd lol won't fadeout.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65934/discussion-between-jqueryking-and-newbie).

Answer (score 0):

Use current context `this` along with selector `.nextAll('.lol:eq(0)')` to target only the desired div.

You will also need to use `mouseleave` instead on `mouseout` and modify the event to fade out the element:

```
 var timer;
   $('.up-score').mouseenter(function(){clearTimeout(timer);$(this).nextAll('.lol:eq(0)').fadeIn(1000)})
   $('.up-score').mouseleave(function(){timer = setTimeout(function()$(this).nextAll('.lol:eq(0)').fadeOut(1000);}, 500);});
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/458z08gz/)**

Comment: Doesn't fade out on mouse out =(

Comment: @MilindAnantwar _but the OP want with setTimeOut

Answer (score 0):

You need to do this:

```
$('.up-score').mouseenter(function () {
    $(this).next('.vframe').next('.lol').fadeIn(1000)
});
$('.up-score').mouseout(function () {
    $(this).next('.vframe').next('.lol').fadeOut(1000);
});
```